# Help creating a more insightful proof looking at closures of a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My lecture notes from my metric space course contained the following practice questions.

[image]

I am getting very confused by this question because I found the following statement on wikipedia *"A metric space is said to be precompact if every sequence admits a Cauchy subsequence. Thus for metric spaces we have: compactness = precompactness + completeness. It turns out that the space is precompact if and only if it is totally bounded. Therefore both names can be used interchangeably."*

I'm under the impression that precompact and relatively compact are the same thing. Does this mean I can prove part b) without assuming completeness? If so, does anyone have a potential proof or outline of one for this fact? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm just shooting with the definitions.

Take the metric space $X = (0,1)$ with the set $A=(0,1)$ and the usual metric. Every sequence in $A$ admits a cauchy subsequence. In fact, every bounded sequence in $R$ (in particular $(0,1)$) admits a convergent subsequence, but it also is Cauchy. By the definition, this set $A$ is precompact.

However, the closure of $A$ is $A=X$ and this is not compact for the same reason $(0,1)$ is not compact in $R$. For instance, $x_n = 1/n$ is in $X$ but doesn't converge in $X$. Hence you can create a subcover that has no finite subcover. That is $A$ is not relatively compact.

Basically any limit points that would otherwise exist don't exist in $X$. But if they did, then $X$ would be complete and since it is also precompact, it would also be compact. Get it?